# Which side of "as well as" is emphasised?

Tags: meaning, grammar, stress

I am curious about which side of the expression is stressed when "as well as" is used as a conjunction. For example:

> brave as well as loyal

In this case, which adjective sounds highlighted more? Or do they sound equally important?

PS: For example, a friend of mine says the emphasis is put on the preceding/second noun since it sounds like an unexpected or surplus thing. As such, it is almost like saying "X person was loyal as much as s/he was brave."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd consider 'He is brave as well as loyal.' unusual without prior context perhaps stressing 'his' loyalty. Then, the new quality is stressed in this sentence. //  'He is loyal and brave.' is the unmarked version; this ordering flows better than the alternative.

Comment: I am not sure where but I remember someone saying the stress is in the first adjective when "as well as" is used as a conjunction. So what do you think is its difference from simply using "and" ?

Comment: People losing interest after reading 'as well as'?

Comment: You might make an argument that *brave and loyal* was a simple statement while *brave as well as loyal* implied some kind of contradistinction but generally that would involve semantics as well as grammar…  *brave as well as scared* would seem much more obvious than *brave as well as loyal*